# Personality is not avaliable

Tags: delphi

Pela segunda vez nesses últimos dias, após reiniciar o computador recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro ao tentar abrir o projeto no Delphi X5 que já tenho trabalhado a muitos meses:

> The project can not be loaded because the requiser personality Delphi.Personality is not available..

Como posso resolver este problema?[image: SS]

[Atualizado]
Por algum motivo, entrando com o usuário Administrador, consigo utilizar normalmente. Alguém sabe se isso é devido a alguma falta de algum registro do windows? lembrei que fiz uma limpeza e desfragmentação do Registro do Windows usando Advanced System Care e Norton Utilities, talvez nessa limpeza, algum registro tenha sido removido indevidamente.

Comment: Eu imagino que você atualizou para o Delhi X5 nesses dias, certo? Alguma coisa não deu certo. Se não, dê mais detalhes. A não ser que seja um erro bem conhecido dificilmente será possível reproduzi-lo, especialmente com tão poucos detalhes.

Comment: [Atualizado]
Por algum motivo, entrando com o usuário Administrador, consigo utilizar normalmente. Alguém sabe se isso é devido a alguma falta de algum registro do windows? lembrei que fiz uma limpeza e desfragmentação do Registro do Windows usando Advanced System Care e Norton Utilities, talvez nessa limpeza, algum registro tenha sido removido indevidamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi desinstalar o Software "Advanced System Care" que estava "Limpando" indevidamente alguns registros do Delphi, gerando o erro.